# on cscope, can I list up function names with some word?

Tags: vim, ctags, cscope

when I use cscope on VIM

I have to type full function name.

for ex

> cscope find s SearchGoIndexOne

it is possible when I know full function name, but not available when I know only a part word.

is there any good solution for this?

or any plugins for replacement with cscope?

Answer (score 3):

You can set cscope to be your tags system with:

`set cst`

This will allow you to use the normal tags functions to perform tag searching.  The `tag` command will complete tag names for you.  E.g.

`:tag MyFunc<TAB>`

Which should give you what you want.  Also don't forget you can use cscope to do regex searches which can also be used to find partial symbol names:

`cscope find e SearchGo.*`

And last but not least, one of the best things you can do with cscope is map some key strokes which work on the word your cursor is on.  This gives you a really slick IDE feel:

```
fun! MapCSKeys()
    nmap cF :cs f f <C-R><C-F><CR>
    nmap cS :cs f s <C-R><C-W><CR>
    nmap cI :cs f i <C-R><C-W><CR>
    nmap cE :cs f e <C-R><C-W><CR>
    nmap cG :cs f g <C-R><C-W><CR>
    nmap cD :cs f d <C-R><C-W><CR>
    nmap cC :cs f c <C-R><C-W><CR>
    nmap cT :cs f t <C-R><C-W><CR>
    nmap cWF :vert scs f f <C-R><C-F><CR>
    nmap cWS :vert scs f s <C-R><C-W><CR>
    nmap cWI :vert scs f i <C-R><C-W><CR>
    nmap cWE :vert scs f e <C-R><C-W><CR>
    nmap cWG :vert scs f g <C-R><C-W><CR>
    nmap cWD :vert scs f d <C-R><C-W><CR>
    nmap cWC :vert scs f c <C-R><C-W><CR>
    nmap cWT :vert scs f t <C-R><C-W><CR>
endfun
```